# Literal and Instance Notations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, literals

I know that there are two main methods of instantiating JavaScript objects.

Where I get confused is where the two types of notations come into their own.

Taking the below samples. Both the instance variables and the literal variables hold different values and both operations on each variable will return a different result.

I have always worked in environments where the Literal notation is used exclusively, however as a .NET programmer I recognise the new keyword and think it makes JavaScript look a little more like c#.

I work in a .NET shop and am currently playing in the WebForms world.

My question is, ***why would you use one over the other and does one play better with ASP.Net WebForms***?

```
var instance1= new Menu1('Cheese', 'Onion');
var instance2 = new Menu1('Steak', 'Kidney');

var literal1 = Menu2;
literal1.Initialise('Fish', 'Chips')
var literal2 = Menu2;
literal2.Initialise('Sausage', 'Mash')
```

**Literal - Original:**

```
var Menu2 = {} | Menu2;

Menu2 =
{
//Properties
Item1 : '',
Item2 :'',

//Functions
Initialise: function(item1, item2)
{
    Item1 = item1;
    Item2 = item2;
},

GetItem : function(item)
{
    switch(item)
    {
        case 'item1':
            return Item1;
        break;

        case 'item2':
            return Item2;
        break;      
    }
}
}
```

**Literal - EDIT:**

```
var Menu2 =
{
//Properties
Item1 : '',
Item2 :'',

//Functions
Initialise: function(item1, item2)
{
    this.Item1 = item1;
    this.Item2 = item2;
},

GetItem : function(item)
{
    switch(item)
    {
        case 'item1':
            return this.Item1;
        break;

        case 'item2':
            return this.Item2;
        break;      
    }
}
}
```

**Instance Notation**

```
var Menu1 = function(item1, item2)
{
var _Item1 = item1;
var _Item2 = item2;

this.GetItem = function(item)
{
    switch(item)
    {
        case 'item1':
            return _Item1;
        break;

        case 'item2':
            return _Item2;
        break;      
    }       
}   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `literal1` and `literal2` are the exact same object

Comment: Your "literal" code has quite a lot wrong with it, unfortunately; it won't work at all as written.

Comment: You are doing bitwise-or in the expression `{} | Menu2`. This gives 0 because NaN | NaN = 0.

Comment: @Pointy - Can you elaborate on this. The code is running fine in Chrome as I type.

Comment: The first `var` declaration will set `Menu2` to `NaN`, because you're doing a bitwise-OR operation between an object and (probably) `undefined`. That doesn't matter, because you immediately reassign `Menu2` anyway. Then, the functions in your object literal refer to `Item1` and `Item2` without using `this` - in all cases those should be `this.Item1` and `this.Item2`. If that works, it's only because you're not in "strict" mode.

Comment: @Pointy - Have made a change to the Literal as above and have set the mode to strict in my html file. Are the edits what you are getting at with your comments??

Comment: @Mom yes that's much better :)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. You would use the `Instance notation` if you want your objects to have a specific type and eventually to have some kind of hierarchy. For example:

```
function Dog(){};

var dog = new Dog();
var dog1 = {};

dog instanceof Dog //true
dog1 instanceof Dog //false
```

The other usage is for cases when you do not want to return specific types but a simple objects from which you will need certain properties.

In simple words, the first notation gives you some OOP which is just a little bit like in languages such as C#. [EcmaScript6 Classes](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html) get a tiny bit closer to this.